# Update field on custom object after it was used in Marketing Cloud email send based on import

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, automation

After an email is sent from automation studio based on file import of a Salesforce report of custom objects, how can we record on that custom object's record that an email was sent?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to using the [v5 Connector](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/). You can only map custom attributes at this time. According to [this FAQ page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/faqs/), mapping to custom objects is on the product road map for the next release.

Comment: I have been using data extensions and custom sender classifcations to include attributes from custom objects in personalization strings within emails. What I'm trying to figure out is how to better to mark on the custom object that an email was sent using those attributes. This would allow me to ensure that record is not used again for a future send as well as allow me to measure the analytic success on the email send and filter by specific shared attributes (from the custom object).